# AJAX XMLHttpRequest cannot load <url> Invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

**UPDATE/FIXED**

Thanks for you your answers. Figured out the problem! (in an programming for dummies way) I am connecting to a remote node server url /page. I got access to this node server & within a file called app.js it had lines of code for cross domain options access. Added line i.e **app.options('url', 'param1', 'param2');** (sorry can't remember exact code) If anyone would like to elaborate their understanding that would be great!

---

Hi everyone be great if you could help me.

I am having a problem with an AJAX post request, my function grabs a value from the user and using a apikey and serial num to post/retrieve data back in json format. I have another function exactly the same that works successfully by entering another id number and url: is different.

Using a simple form request by manually inputting API and serial num retrieves data successfully but AJAX below does not.

Console log error comes back with
OPTIONS....
XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Invalid HTTP status code 404

Am working locally > request remote url. I have CORS extension and I have tried allowing cross origin solution but no luck.

thanks!

```
this.searchModelEvent = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $m = $(this);
var _serial = $m.find(".serialNum").val();

var modelData = { apikey: apikey,id: _serial };
modelData = JSON.stringify(modelData);

console.log(modelData);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: modelUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: 'modelData',
    success: function(data) {
    if (data.error) {
    _t.errorState();                    
    } else {
    console.log("SUCCESS!!@#! \n");
    }
},//End Success
}); //End Ajax Call

};//End Search Model Event
```

Comment: Are you sure `modelUrl` is exactly the same as in your manual tests?

Comment: Yep tested that. swaped variable with http url and vice versa. cheers

Comment: We cant debug what we cant see, where does modelUrl even come from? We have no way of knowing.  Why is your variable ModelData in single quotes? This tells the JS parser that it is a string not a variable.

Comment: I am guessing that your url is not exactly what you think it is. Look at the request in the network panel and look at the url.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to prove this as the solution because it is not a complete set of code, however I would say your main issue (if everything else is in order above and beyond what I mentioned on the OP) is that you need to:

change line

`data: 'modelData',`

to

`data: modelData,`
Like this:

```
this.searchModelEvent = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $m = $(this);
var _serial = $m.find(".serialNum").val();

var modelData = { apikey: apikey,id: _serial };
modelData = JSON.stringify(modelData);

console.log(modelData);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: modelUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: modelData,
    success: function(data) {
    if (data.error) {
    _t.errorState();                    
    } else {
    console.log("SUCCESS!!@#! \n");
    }
},//End Success
}); //End Ajax Call

};//End Search Model Event
```